# Want to pass data to route . How to do It?

Tags: angular

In angular js there is a concept of $state.go and we were able to pass data through
it and that data is used as stateParams not url params .How to do it in new angular? I have used router.navigate and passed data but that data is appending to url but not assigning to stateParams.

Comment: you mean like sending data through an HTTP POST request, for example?

Answer (score 0):

For me the most obvious solution is to use a Service. Before you navigate call the service and save the date and in the "routed to" component retrieve it in the ngOnInit.

I wonder whether this is the easiest / most elegant way to achieve the goal.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {

  private yourData: string;

  getYourData(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(this.yoruData);
  }

  setYourData(dataToBeSaved: string) {
    this.yourData = dataToBeSaved;
  }

}
```

and call it like this

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  parameters: string;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.dataService.getYourData()
        .subscribe(data=> this.parameters = data);
  }
}
```

for saving the parameters you would in the first component inject the service as well and then save the data over calling the method setYourData('bla').

Instead of a string you can create a class for the data you will save.

Comment: You would need to provide a code structure to follow (atleast pseudo)

Answer (score 0):

1- You can either do it using `service`:

- save variable value in service before `router.navigate`
- Then in populated component you can get the value from service

2- You can pass data through `link`:

> This method is used if you want to keep your component independent.
>   Lets say if your comes directly through link instead of navigating through app then still your component will
>   work perfectly. but in case of service you will not be able to get
>   data if user lands on component via url

**That is how you can do it with second method**

To pass value from compoent first import Router

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

now in constructor

```
constructor(public router: Router) {
  }
```

then you can route to component like this

```
this.router.navigate(['link_of_component', 'Param_1','Param_2');
```

**You will have to add route in `Routes` like this**

```
{path: 'link_of_component/:Param_1/:Param_2', component: YourComponent}
```

**Now to get value in second component**

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
```

In constructor

```
constructor(
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
```

and you can get value like this

```
const paramOne = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('Param_1');
const paramTwo = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('Param_2');
```

Comment: i don't want to pass parameters to path   {
    "path": "/url",
    "component": component name,
    "data": {product name: 'Intraday',group:'A'}
  },  i wanted to pass parameter to 'data' part not to path from another component on click event